# BigQuery GetQuery result API is giving duplicate entry

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have create a BigQuery Sink to export the query logs i.e to have analytic data over the query my Sink filter

```
protoPayload.methodName="jobservice.getqueryresults"
```

When i run a query on Big query i am seeing two entry in the result i.e for single query run two logs are generated how to make sure we have only one unique logs per query.

[image: As you can see i am getting multiple rows for the query]

Is it because my service is calling the api twice ?

```
 "GET /bigquery/v2/projects/bq-project/queries/cef367ca-89b4-4ab9-b255-4285435197bd?maxResults=0&location=US&prettyPrint=false HTTP/1.1" 200 None
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://bigquery.googleapis.com:443 "GET /bigquery/v2/projects/bq-project/queries/cef367ca-89b4-4ab9-b255-4285435197bd?fields=jobReference%2CtotalRows%2CpageToken%2
```

Is there any way in i can assure that there would be only one entry per query ?

Comment: What do you want to have as data in your analytics table to perform stuff?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere i want to have details `query`, `user`, `source`, ` execution time` , `schema`, `tables`  query related stuff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the required data, I recommend you to use this filter for you sink

```
resource.type="bigquery_resource"
protoPayload.serviceData.jobCompletedEvent.job.jobStatus.state="DONE"
protoPayload.methodName="jobservice.jobcompleted"
```

Indeed, the JobCompleted in state DONE provide you all the information at the end of the request.

The GetQueryResult is a query to BigQuery to fetch the data. If you fettch page of 10 rows for a total of 200 rows, you will have 20 entries of the same request, with the same information as the JobCompleted entry.

Comment: i am not getting the query logs it's mostly the `load_job` logs

Comment: if i do `select * from my datasets`  i am not getting this logs